# WiFi Authentication Without MAC Address (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, security, wifi, network-security

I’m currently working on a small project with the goal of using an iOS App to provide a secure, centralized login for a network of WiFi hotspots in small and medium sized businesses. The plan was to configure the routers as open networks and DHCP forward all the traffic from the router to our (cloud-hosted) server, where each query is authenticated and the user’s query is allowed to pass to its intended destination.

Our current problem is that in order to configure the server to know which users are accessing it we need the Mac Addresses of the users, which the Apple API requires they type in manually the first time they use the app (which is a lot of work) so we are trying to come up with a work around.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

:)

Comment: It's not clear what you are using the MAC address for. Is this to authenticate the WiFi or your server login? Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope I can clarify. Because the users can disconnect and reconnect from the network we can't use their IP address for login, so we need the MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7 you can no longer get the MAC Address.  Based on what you are trying to do, I would recommend using one of the device identifiers available through iOS like `identifierForVendor` which will give you an unique id.

as per Apple Docs:

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)